# Color being applied to select option text. Causing text to be hidden

Tags: html, css, sass

I've encountered an issue with my select element on Chrome for Windows, however I do not encounter it on Chrome for Mac OSX. (Please see the screenshots below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/92qLS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpDg8.png

I'm not applying any styles directly to the option element, though it may inherit styles. Below is my CSS; note: I'm using SCSS.

```
.site-page--archive__dropdown select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: #43cdcb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

.site-page--archive__dropdown select:focus {
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.site-page--archive__dropdown select:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

If anyone has come across this before it'd be great if you could let me know how you resolved it?

Comment: In what sense? I'm providing it above. Nothing there (other than & and variables is different to pure CSS)

Comment: This isn't a Sass problem, so only provide the compiled CSS.  Your Sass doesn't compile because you didn't initialize the variables you're using.  This is all very annoying and time consuming, making it less likely for people to be willing to help you.

Comment: I understand; I'll provide the compiled source.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is enough code here to debug the problem. [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bo0SzdiGFjikHPeJiuKb?p=preview) is the plunk with the fixed version. The problem with color in select is that all the children inherit the color as long as you do not over ride it.

Give additional styling to 'select option' as you seem fit and it should be fine. I have done the same in the plunkr for your perusal. You can try to remove the 'select option' styling to find that your problem is reproducible. Let me know how that works.

Here is the css which would work for you:

```
select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        position: relative;
        height: 40px;
        width: 120%;
        border: none;
        background: none;
        color: black;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }

select:focus {
            border: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            outline: none;
        }

        select:hover {
            color: #fff;
        }
select option {
            color: black;;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought it might be that. I'll test it and let you know if it worked. Thank you very much!